# Warning message on removing a row in QFormLayout

Tags: pyqt5, qformlayout

I have a QFormLayout with several rows in it.  Including one row with another QFormLayout.  I want to delete a row and insert another row.  Although I can get it to work there is a message every time I delete a row:

QFormLayout::takeAt: Invalid index 0

I'm not sure if I am doing something wrong by embedding a form inside another, but there is clearly an issue

An example of the code that shows this behaviour is shown below:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QFormLayout, QLabel, QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPalette, QColor

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle("My App")
        layout = QFormLayout()
        layout.addRow(QLabel('red'),Color('red'))
        layout.addRow(QLabel('green'),Color('green'))
        insideLayout = QFormLayout()
        insideLayout.addRow(QLabel('label 1'),QPushButton('Label 1'))
        insideLayout.addRow(QLabel('label 2'),QPushButton('Label 2'))
        layout.addRow(QLabel('inside'),insideLayout)
        row = layout.rowCount()-1
        layout.addRow(QLabel('blue'),Color('blue'))
        layout.removeRow(row)

        widget = QWidget()
        widget.setLayout(layout)
```

I was expecting to be able to remove a row in the QFormLayout fairly straightforwardly.  I haven't tried any other approaches.

Comment: Use `layout.takeRow(row)` instead.

Comment: @ekhumoro It seems like the warning is just there to *warn* about the "wrong" index caused by the internal call to `takeAt(0)` done in the while loop of `clearAndDestroyQLayoutItem` of the "parent" QFormLayout), but that doesn't change the behavior. In reality, `takeRow()` may even be the wrong choice, if not used with awareness, since it doesn't change the parent nor delete the contents of the item.

Comment: @musicamante The OP wants to eliminate the warning message. The only feasible alternative (as your own answer shows), is to use [takeRow](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qformlayout.html#takeRow) (or [takeAt](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qformlayout.html#takeAt)). My previous comment leaves the rest as an exercise for the reader ;-)

Answer (score 1):

### tl;dr

That is a warning caused by internal calls of QFormLayout (specifically, the "parent" one you are using).

The expected behavior is still achieved, as it doesn't affect the result, so you can safely ignore it.

### Explanation

An important thing to be aware of is that layout managers in Qt use the base [QLayoutItem](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlayoutitem.html) class, which is an abstract object that represents an *item* within a layout: that could be a widget, a spacer, or even a further *nested* layout. This is done to have a transparent interface, so that the layout can access the items size hints/policies/restraints and set their geometries no matter of (or considering) the item type.

Interestingly, a QLayout (which is the basis for all Qt layouts) also inherits from QLayoutItem, and there is no real restriction about what it could represent: it could be *empty* (no widget, no spacer and no layout) or, theoretically, represent a combination of them (unlikely, but not strictly forbidden).

Now, `removeRow()` uses a private `clearAndDestroyQLayoutItem()` static function, with a `while` loop that calls `takeAt` for items that represent a layout so that it *clears* all the contents of that item, eventually calling itself recursively whenever it represents a nested layout.

This is what happens when `removeRow()` is called:

- get the pair of QLayoutItems (`label` and `field`) for the given row;
- call `clearAndDestroyQLayoutItem()` with both of them, which will do the following:
- if it is a widget, delete it;
- if it is a layout, then do a `while` that loops while calls to `takeAt(0)` return a valid QLayoutItem;

  - call `clearAndDestroyQLayoutItem()` with that result;

This can be approximately translated into Python like this:

```py
def clearAndDestroyQLayoutItem(item):
    if item:
        widget = item.widget()
        if widget:
            widget.deleteLater()
        layout = item.layout()
        if layout is not None:
            while child := layout.takeAt(0) is not None:
                 clearAndDestroyQLayoutItem(child)
            layout.deleteLater() # extra safety, not in the original C++ code


class QFormLayout(QLayout):
    ...
    def removeRow(self, row):
        res = self.takeRow(row)
        clearAndDestroyQLayoutItem(result.labelItem)
        clearAndDestroyQLayoutItem(result.fieldItem)
```

<sup>Notes: 1. the C++ code actually uses `delete` for the widget, but Python that doesn't work in the same way (and `del` isn't acceptable), so `deleteLater` is safer; an alternative *may* be to use `sip.delete()`, but that should be used with extreme care (it would probably crash in your case); 2. the `if layout is not None:` is required because the `__bool__` operator of QLayout is overridden in PyQt, returning `False` if the layout has no items even if a layout object exists; 3. the `while` loop above uses the assignment operator introduced in Python 3.8.</sup>

In any case, what's important is that `takeAt(0)` is always called until it returns nothing (the layout is empty). The default implementation requires it to return `nullptr` in C++ (`None` in Python) if no layout item exists at the given index, and QFormLayout follows that correctly.

The only difference with other layout managers is the warning QFormLayout produces, which was probably put there for "lazy preventive debugging", but it doesn't change its behavior and shouldn't create any issue, unless the destroyed objects in that row are implemented in some weird or extremely complex ways (which would probably present other issues anyways).

As said above, you can safely ignore that warning in normal cases like the one you provided.